# Copy link library files for conda build

Tags: conda, conda-build

I am trying to prepare a conda build for a [package](https://github.com/abyzovlab/CNVnator) and the package depends on [samtools](https://github.com/samtools/samtools/releases) libraries. The user needs to copy the library files into the package directory for compilation. Here is the installation instruction of the package.

```
ln -s <path_to_samtools_dir> samtools
make OMP=no # without parallel support
```

I am not sure how to configure that part for conda-build.

The requirements section of my `meta.yml` file

```
requirements:
  build:
    - {{ compiler('c') }}
    - samtools
    - htslib
    - cmake
    - readline
    - zlib
  Host:
    - samtools
    - htslib
  run:
    - samtools
    - htslib
    - python
    - numpy >=1.16
    - root
    - matplotlib
    - readline
```

Comment: Is there any way to specify a separate directory for the `samtools`? You could specify the `ln` command as part of your `build.sh` but that's not super reproducible and might be a little fragile.

Comment: Using `build.sh`, I can copy/soft link the `samtools` library files. But how to find the samtools library files in conda env?

Comment: They will be installed in `$PREFIX/lib`, I think. See here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/environment-variables.html